# How can I change the value of input in react test

Tags: reactjs, testing

I'd like to test a form of my react-app.

I have removed 'disabled' property of button when doing following things.

```
const component = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<Mycomponent/>);
const myDOM =findDOMNode(component);
const input = myDOM.querySelector('input');
input.value = "2017-11-11";
let submitButton = myDOM.querySelector('button');
TestUtils.Simulate.click(submitButton);
...
const newlyAddedDate = record.querySelector('#date').innerHTML;
console.log("newlyAddedDate:"+newlyAddedDate);
```

but the output in console is

```
"newlyAddedDate:"
```

This react-app performs correctly in chrome.
I believe it's the problem of

```
"input.value="2017-11-11";
```

This sentence failed to change the value in the inputbox.

So how can i set the value in a inputbox when doing react-test?

Here's the repo of this app
https://github.com/zzbslayer/ChargeAccount-React

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it totally depends on what libraries you use for testing. Here's a sample using Mocha and Enzyme combination.

```
 beforeEach(() => {
      _spies = {}
      _props = {
        propOne: 'somepropvalue',
        ...
      }
      _wrapper = mount(<Your Component {..._props} />)
    })



    it('Should change the input box', () => {
      let promptInput = _wrapper.find('textarea')

      promptInput.simulate('change', { target: { value : 'sample2' } })
    })
```

In before method you initialize your component, by passing all the props down. Then inside your test you find that text box inside the wrapper using a selector or HTML id of that element. Then you simulate a change event with the new value.

Notice that Jest has become a defacto framework for testing nowadays in most of the react starter boilerplate. In that case the concepts remains the same, but the syntax differs.

Comment: Thanks very much! I find I didn't simulate change of the input box!